# Is there Google Hosted Version of these jQuery plugins?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hello Could find the google hosted version of javscripts

timeago.js - timeago: a jQuery plugin, version: 0.8.2

jquery.popup-min.js  - ColorBox v1.3.6 - a full featured, light-weight, customizable lightbox based on jQuery 1.3

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK the answer is No, google only hosts the larger main library.

Answer (score 2):

No, google does not host plugins.  However, the jQuery team is working on a CDN for this hosted by Media Temple.

[You can see the state of jQuery 2009 here](http://www.slideshare.net/jeresig/state-of-jquery-09), look at item #29 for the cliff notes:

> Revamped Plugins Site ✤ Features: ✤ All plugins are hosted on the new CDN. ✤ (Along with an auto-miniﬁed version of the plugin.) ✤ Dependency trees are auto-computed and made available for download. ✤ Documentation is mirrored, formatted, and made available as part of the API. ✤ Shooting to launch by the end of this year.